# arm or mips core to implement in fpga

Tags: arm, mips, fpga

I am trying to implement a risc processor core in fpga. Is it a good idea to do such a project. I am confused whether to implement an arm core or mips core. Please tell me which would be a better option consider that i am a starter in this field.

Comment: I've written an ARMv5T emulator once, and I'd wager that MIPS32 (with no FPU) would be simpler. Both would be fairly ambitious projects though, especially if you've never done anything similar before.

Comment: if you want to use existing cores, go to opencores.org and get either the amber core or mpx (armv2 or mips).  From scratch one is as good as the other, mips has the branch shadow thing that you would have to implement, arm's instruction decoder is not as straightforward as mips.  In both cases you need to avoid their patents, so avoid armv4 or newer or follow the model that the other open mips cores do and avoid certain instructions.

Comment: if you have not done a processor before do something much simpler like a lc3 or risc16 or pic12 or 14 then maybe pdp11/msp430 then work your way up to an arm or risc.  (the first three lc3, risc16, pic12, should take only a few dozen minutes to write the processor core, the whole project with testing an evening or afternoon).

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes such a project would be pretty cool and you would learn a lot. That being said I believe you should build smaller things first. As for ARM vs. MIPS, the complexity is equivalent, but I would pick ARM cause it's actually the most popular processor architecture in the world right now, so the knowledge you would gain would be highly practical.
2. I recommend starting with a book called "CODE". It will teach you all the basics in a very clear way. Once you read that you should be able to build logic gates, full adders and even a simple generic purpose computer, all using nothing but relays and wires.
3. Once you've done those smaller projects then try something larger with transistors, protoboards or FGPA. One very interesting computer you could build is the IAS, also called the Von Neumann machine, which is the base for all modern computers (yet is very simple and elegant).

Comment: ok. Thank you very much for your reply. It was quite informative